# allow one thread to go, one to wait, and drop the others

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an observer that can be called several times. If the `onChange` method of the observer is still running a second call should wait and the following calls should be ignored.

I used this:

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2,false);
...
public void onChange() {
    if (!semaphore.tryAcquire()) return;
    synchronized (semaphore) { 
        // do your stuff
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

Is this ok? Is there a better way?

Comment: This won't stop the other threads to retry after the semaphore is released. Also the permit should be 1 based on your description.

Comment: It's correct if the thread can run if the other called release. And Are you sure it should be 1? In that case the second thread will be dropped right?

Comment: You're right 2 is ok. But still the semaphore won't reject the threads when the permit becomes zero, only tells them to wait. (So they are not "ignored".)

Comment: @david: That's taken care of by the "try" in `tryAcquire()`, right?

Comment: Right... I thought the threads will repeatedly try to acquire from a queue but if not it is correct.

Comment: Yes tryAquire returns false if all the permissions are already taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic looks good to me.  As I read it 2 threads will be able to acquire the `Semaphore` in any order.  Any other threads trying to acquire will return and be ignored.

The first thread to do the `synchronized` will block the other one so only one thread will be working and one (max) will be waiting.  As soon as the job has been completed and `release()` is called then another thread will be allowed into the semaphore.  As soon as a the `synchronized` block completes, the first waiting thread will start to work.

Another way to do it would be with two `Semaphore` objects with the 2nd one doing a `acquire` instead of a `tryAcquire`.  But your way should work.

As @herschel pointed out, I would do a `try/finally` around "do your stuff" to guarantee that the semaphore is released.  Something like:

```
...
synchronized (semaphore) {
    try {
        // do your stuff
    } finally {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a true instead of the false in the contructor otherwise the order is  not always respected

Comment: Right sorry I should have added that the order is not really important. All the thread will do the same thing. That's why if one is already in the queue the others can die

Comment: Another thing to add is that "do your stuff" must not throw otherwise the semaphore won't be released